# Merge dataframe dynamic

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 2 dataframes: df1 and df2. I would like to merge the 2 dataframes on the column link in df2. Link column in df2 contains a list of column and values which match in df1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'p':[1,2,3,4], 'a':[1,2,2,2],'b':['z','z','z','z'],'c':[3,3,4,4],'d':[5,5,5,6]})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'e':[11,22,33,44], 'link':['a=1,c=3','a=2,c=3','a=2,c=4,d=5','a=2,c=4']})
```

The result should end with dataframe like this where column e from df2 are merge together with df1:

```
df_res = pd.DataFrame({'p':[1,2,3,3,4], 'a':[1,2,2,2,2],'b':['z','z','z','z','z'],'c':[3,3,4,4,4],'d':[5,5,5,5,6],'e':[11,22,33,44,44]})
```

How can this be done in pandas?

Comment: Why are there five rows in the output dataframe and four rows for the input dataframes?

Comment: On what basis is the linking supposed to occur?

Answer (score 0):

```
df1["e"] = df2["e"]
```

[image]

Comment: In the sample there are 4 rows in both. Try to see here where one row from df1 end up with two rows in the result: https://i.imgur.com/jk2m7jU.png
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/jk2m7jU.png">

Answer (score 0):

```
frames = [df1, df2]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

Comment: try to see my screendump. each row from df2 should be dynamic linked based on contend in column link in df2.